# using and in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
function advertiser_validate()
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var firstname = $('firstname').val();
   var lastname = $('lastname').val();
   var username= $('username').val();
   var email = $('#user_email').val();
   var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
**if(firstname.length > 0) && (lastname.length > 0) && (username.length > 0) && (regex.test(email) === true)**
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   if(firstname.length < 1)
   {
   $('.f_name').html('Please enter the first name');
}
   if(lastname.length < 1)
   {
   $('.l_name').html('Please enter the Last name');
}
   if(username.length < 1)
   {
   $('.username_vali').html('Please enter the username');
}   
if((regex.test(email) === false))
{
   $('.email').html('Please enter the valid email');
}
return false;
}
});    
}
</script>
```

Friends from the above jquery code i'm validating my form but when i use the combine validation of variables using && operator the browser is returning error in the below format .
How can I achieve this

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&&'

if(firstname.length > 0) && (lastname.length > 0) && (username.length > 0) &&
```

Comment: Brackets. `if (a > 0 && b > 0 && ...)` or `if ( (a > 0) && (b > 0) && ...)`

Comment: replace your if statement with this: if( (firstname.length > 0) && (lastname.length > 0) && (username.length > 0) && (regex.test(email) === true) )

Comment: *"using and in jquery"* - Note that this error isn't related to jQuery, it's just a Javascript syntax error.

Comment: @nnnnnn and what about Php tag :p

Comment: @devpro do you see any php tag!!!! open eyes man.

Comment: @jai eyes ..ahan its open chk revision... :p

Comment: @jai this is for u http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35938602/revisions

Comment: Agreed @devpro. good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `ALL &&` conditions than no need yo use extra brackets:

**Example**:

```
if(firstname.length > 0 && lastname.length > 0 && username.length > 0 && regex.test(email) === true){
   // your stuff
}
```

Or if you want to fix your condition:

```
if((firstname.length > 0) && (lastname.length > 0) && (username.length > 0) && (regex.test(email) === true)){
    //your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
advertiser_validate()
});
function advertiser_validate()
{

   var firstname = $('firstname').val();
   var lastname = $('lastname').val();
   var username= $('username').val();
   var email = $('#user_email').val();
   var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if((firstname.length > 0) && (lastname.length > 0) && (username.length > 0) && (regex.test(email) === true))
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   if(firstname.length < 1)
   {
   $('.f_name').html('Please enter the first name');
}
   if(lastname.length < 1)
   {
   $('.l_name').html('Please enter the Last name');
}
   if(username.length < 1)
   {
   $('.username_vali').html('Please enter the username');
}   
if((regex.test(email) === false))
{
   $('.email').html('Please enter the valid email');
}
return false;
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Plz also add some explanation

Comment: Let's play a game of "Spot the Differences".

Comment: He put ( ) around the combined if statements that's what gets it working!

Comment: Sorry i spoilered the game xd